# Delete related model correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

My store function is

```
public function store(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->fill($request->all());
    $post->comments()->save($comment);
}
```

And my destroy function is

```
public function destroy(Post $post, Comment $comment)
{

}
```

Store function I got from documentation ([Inserting & Updating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models))

So what is the best practice to delete a comment through the Post model?

Comment: in database table comment, set a FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE , when you delete a post, it will delete all comment associate the post

Comment: What are the relationships between Post and Comment? I would assume Post `hasMany` Comments and Comment `belongsTo` Post?

Comment: Jonathon, yes..

Comment: oops you want use one controller to handle post and comment ? suppose post controller is handle post, comment controller is handle comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your relationships are `hasMany` and `belongsTo`, you don't really need to delete a comment *through* a post. The comment exists as its own record in its own table and is associated to a post through a `post_id` if you have adhered to Laravel's naming conventions.

In which case, to delete a comment, you just simply need to use the [`delete`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#deleting-models) method:

```
public function destroy(Post $post, Comment $comment)
{
    $comment->delete();
}
```

If you're using the `SoftDeletes` trait on the `Comment` model, this will simply set `deleted_at` to the current timestamp. If not, it will remove the record from the database. If you are using `SoftDeletes` and want to remove the record from the table (instead of just setting `deleted_at`) you can use [`forceDelete`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models) (See under *Permanently Deleting Models*):

```
public function destroy(Post $post, Comment $comment)
{
    $comment->forceDelete();
}
```

If you want to simply destroy the reference between the comment and the post you could use the [`dissociate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) method on the comment object. This will effectively just set the `post_id` field to `null` and won't delete the comment from the table.

```
public function destroy(Post $post, Comment $comment)
{
    $comment->post()->dissociate();
    $comment->save();
}
```

If you really want to use the relationship to ensure that only comments that belong to the given post can be deleted, you could do this:

```
$post->comments()->whereKey($comment->id)->delete();
```

That would add an extra `where` to the query ensuring that the comment has `post_id` equal to the post's ID.

For reference, if you had a many to many relationship (`belongsToMany` both directions) you would need to delete the record in the pivot table. To do that you would use `detach` or you could use `sync` to only provide what should remain.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. So I do not have to make sure that the comment belongs to the post?

Comment: It's up to you really and depends on your application. If you want to do such a check you can easily do it before deleting by checking that `$comment->post_id == $post->id`. Laravel doesn't provide a method for checking and deleting related models in the way you describe though, as far as I know.

Comment: You could if you wanted to go through the relation do: `$post->comments()->whereKey($comment->id)->delete()` for a similar effect but it's not really necessary. That would result in a query that ensures the `post_id` in the `comments` table matches the ID of the post.

Comment: Thank you Jonathon

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Laravel Observer here is an example

for creating observer you can

```
php artisan make:observer PostObserver
```

It will create a nice boilerplate.

```
class PostObserver
{

    public function deleting(Post $post){

        $comments =  $post->comments;
        $comments->delete();
    }

}
```

in your AppServiceProvider.php

```
Post::observe(PostObserver);
```

it will delete the related models before you are deleting the Post.

Comment: I would like to know the reasons for the down voting?

Comment: because your answer is not useful and I got the impression that you have not read my question at all.

Comment: I just wanted to delete one comment with my CommentController function destroy, but you suggest me to create observer with other functionality. Thanks, but for that is have $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id') ->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');